# status of a 4-team group in football worldcup

Tags: python

we have a group which it has 4 teams in and the six games between them.
I want to write a program that, upon receiving the results of the games, will print the team name, the number of wins and losses, and the difference in goals and points respectively in one line. Each team should be printed in order of points in one line. (If the points are equal, the number of wins will be considered. If both the number of wins and the points are equal, they will be printed in alphabetical order.)

Note: The team gets zero points in case of loss, one point in case of draw and three points in case of win.
Goal difference is the difference between goals scored and goals conceded by a team.
I sorted the games between them like:

```
team_a and team_b
team_a and team_c
team_a and team_d
team_b and team_c
team_b and team_d
team_c and team_d
```

in this program the matches above are fixed, but the result is variable and would get from user as inputs.

e.g:
inputs:

```
2-2
2-1
1-2
2-2
3-1
2-1
```

and output will be:

```
team_a wins:1 , loses:1 , draws:1 , goal difference:0 , points:4
team_b wins:1 , loses:0 , draws:2 , goal difference:2 , points:5
team_c wins:1 , loses:1 , draws:1 , goal difference:0 , points:4
team_d wins:1 , loses:2 , draws:0 , goal difference:-2 , points:3
```

I have some problems:
how can I print "goal difference"?
how can I count the wins and loses and etc for each team?

Comment: it is better to try first, and if you found any issue in your code, then ask here.

Comment: I tried and I can get the results and save them in a list , but can not compare for each team I do not know how to relate point to each team